# How does the "this" keyword work with objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, iteration, symbols

Since I'm trying to grasp the concept of iterables in JavaScript, I built one with the following code:

```
let range = {
  from: 0,
  to: 5
};

range[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  return {
    current: this.from,
    last: this.to,

    next() {
      if (this.current <= this.last) {
        return { done: false, value: this.current++ };
      } else {
        return { done: true };
      }
    }
  };
};

for (let num of range) {
  console.log(num);
}
```

The `Symbol.iterator` method returns an object that contains one method (`next`) and two properties (`current` and `from`). The properties within this object are equal to the properties within the object `range`.

Since `current` equals `this.from` and `last` equals `this.to`, I assumed that I could use `this.from` and `this.to` directly from within the method `next` as so:

```
let range = {
  from: 0,
  to: 5
};

range[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  return {
    next() {
      if (this.from <= this.to) {
        return { done: false, value: this.from++ };
      } else {
        return { done: true };
      }
    }
  };
};

for (let num of range) {
  console.log(num);
}
```

However, doing this prevented the iteration from starting. Having observed this, I have two questions:

1. Why *can* the properties `current` and `last` use the keyword `this` and have it refer to the object `range` whereas the method `next` cannot? `current`, `last`, and `next()` are all part of the *same* object, which is returned by `Symbol.iterator`.
2. Also, given that `Symbol.iterator()` returns a *separate* object, shouldn't the `this` keyword within that object refer to that object itself? In other words, shouldn't the properties `current` and `last` *not* be able to access the properties from `range` using the keyword `this`? Isn't `range` a separate object?

Comment: One usage of `this` is inside the `[Symbol.iterator]` method, the other in the `.next` method. Object literals don't matter, they don't have their own scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `this` is complicated. It is wise to avoid using it when there are better alternatives, which there usually are, because it has many gotchas.

With that out of the way, here's the answer: `this` refers to the *activation object* (sometimes referred to as *context object*) that its containing function was called with.

What is the activation object? It is the object the function was attached to when it was called. The activation object for `console.log()` is `console`.

However...

```
const x = {
    log : console.log
};
x.log();
```

... here `x.log()` is exactly the same as `console.log()`, except the activation object is `x` instead of `console`.

Seems pretty simple, right? It is, sort of. But there's more things to know.

- There is a default context object, used when a function is called without being attached to an object. It is the global object, known as `window` in the browser and `global` in Node.js.
- If the script is running in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), then there is no default context object and it will be `undefined` if not explicitly called with a context
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) use lexical scoping and their `this` value is not the usual context object at all - it is the context object of its parent function from wherever the arrow function was defined

Now let's take the above and apply it to your code. Most importantly, your `next()` method would work if it were called with the context being the `range` object. The problem is, under the hood, the engine is basically doing this...

```
const returnedObject = range[Symbol.iterator]();
returnedObject.next();
```

... so `next` is being called with `returnedObject` as its context, rather than `range`. But the function which returned the object *is* called with `range` as its context. Thus, `this` is different in each place.

You can actually fix your problem very easily by using an arrow function instead of a shorthand method.

This will work:

```
let range = {
  from: 0,
  to: 5
};

range[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  return {
    next : () => {
      if (this.from <= this.to) {
        return { done: false, value: this.from++ };
      } else {
        return { done: true };
      }
    }
  };
};

for (let num of range) {
  console.log(num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*this* is known to be a tricky thing. So much so that Kyle Simpson dedicated almost a whole book to the topic ([You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md)). However, in your example the answer is easy - in the second function, *this* is within the `next()` function and so, resolves to this function.

To check the scope of *this*, I am using Chrome's debugging tool. If you pause at the right line, it tells you what *this* resolves to.

Comment: That makes sense. However, then why do the properties `current` and `last` (both of whose values involve `this`) resolve to the `range` object and not to their own object?

Comment: Closure and prototypal inheritance. This says hey I am sort of this closure(function/object)

Comment: `current: this.from` happens within the `range` object and so, `this` refers to `range`. In the second snippet, `this` is used within the scope of the `next()` function.